# recalling a certain variable in a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

```
game = "y"
while game =="y":
    game = raw_input("Would you like start a new game? (y/n): ")
    if game == "y":
        name = raw_input("Name of person: ")
        num = raw_input("Your favourite number: ")
        print name, num
    if game == "n":
        print "game over"
        break
```

So I have this loop going.  After this loop, I want to recall the name of the person with the highest favourite number and the number itself.  How do I store the values inside this infinite while loop?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could have variables that store the max_num and max_name, if the current num is bigger than max, then update max_num and max_name with it.  Feel free to choose better variable names if you prefer something else.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following with.  Here is a code example.

```
game = "y"
maxName = ""
maxNumber = 0
while game =="y":
    game = raw_input("Would you like start a new game? (y/n): ")
    if game == "y":
        name = raw_input("Name of person: ")
        num = raw_input("Your favourite number: ")
        if int(num) > maxNumber:
            maxNumber = int(num)
            maxName = name
        print name, num
    if game == "n":
        print "game over"
        print "The winner is " + str(maxName) + " with a score of " + str(maxNumber)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using auxiliar vars to store the name and the score and add an if to check the score stored against current... so if the current is higher you update the name and score of the highest...

something like pseudo code will be...

```
stored_name = ""
stored_score = 0
while "condition"
current_name
current_score
if current_score > stored_score
   //update vars
   stored_name = current_name
   stored_score = current_score
```

ps: just like the post above... hahaha